# Authorization based on access groups

Tags: authorization

I'm building a backend application, and this is how I want authorization to work:

I have a `User` entity which can have one of the following roles: `superAdmin`, `manager` and `worker`.

Also, I have a `Company` entity. Each `Company` has `Users` assigned to it, and several other entities (for example, `Company settings`).

`superAdmin` can access all `Users` and `Companies` with their related entities, they are not bound to any `Company`. `manager` is assigned to only one `Company`, and can access only this `Company` and `Users` (both `managers` and `workers`) assigned to this `Company`. `worker` is also assigned to only one `Company` and can access only some entities under their `Company`.

It seems to me that `Company` entity acts as an access group. How this type of authorization is called?